# AVG in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join, average, aggregate-functions

I am learning SQL Server, and I have a sample database which I got from my co-worker.

I created a stored procedure previously which works fine. Now I am trying to show average of the column which I am struggling at the moment.

Your supports means a lot and I will learn from this.

So here is my query:

```
SELECT  
    CONCAT(ud.FirstName, ',', ud.LastName) AS 'Name',
    tech.TechnoName AS 'Techno',
    (rt.Rating) AS 'Rating', rt.FeedBackType,
    rt.Description, rt.ProgramId 
FROM 
    Rating rt, Techno tech, Program pd, User ud
WHERE 
    pd.Id = ud.UserID AND
    pd.TechnoId = tech.TechnoID AND
    rt.PdId = pd.Id
GROUP BY 
    pd.Id, ud.FirstName, ud.LastName, tech.TechnoName, 
    rt.Rating, rt.PdId, rt.Description, rt.FeedBackType
ORDER BY 
    rt.PdId
```

And my table is like

```
    Name    Techno    Rating    FeedbackType    Description     ProgramId
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    A,B       C#         4          1             ***              100
    A,B       C#         5          1             ***              102
    B,B       JS         4          3             ***              106
    B,C       C++        3          1             ***              280
    B,C       C          5          1             ***              300
```

And Now I want to show the avg rating based on the name and techno column such that my table should be like

```
Name    Techno     Rating    
--------------------------
A,B       C#         4.5          
B,B       JS         4          
B,C       C++        3          
B,C       C          5
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Remove the other columns (e.g. `FeedBackType`) from your `SELECT` and `GROUP BY`, then apply the `Avg()` aggregate function to `Rating`.

Comment: Start over - you are learning BAD habits. Use JOINs - not the 9old-style join via where clause](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)!

Comment: And stop cramming your code together. Readable code is always better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to adapt the `group by` clause to generate the one row per name and techno, and use an aggregate function to compute the rating:

```
select  
    concat(ud.firstname,',',ud.lastname) as name, 
    tech.technoname as techno,
    avg(1.0 * rt.rating) as rating
from rating rt
inner join program pd on rt.pdid = pd.id 
inner join techno tech on pd.technoid = tech.technoid
inner join user ud opn pd.id = ud.userid
group by ud.firstname, ud.lastname, tech.technoname
order by ud.firstname, ud.lastname
```

Important notes:

- Use standard joins! Implicit joins (with commas in the `from` clause and joining conditions in the `where` clause) are legacy syntax from decades ago, that should be used in new code
- Do not use single quotes as quoting character for identifiers; use the relevant quoting character for your platform (in SQL Server, square brackets) - or better yet, use identifiers that do not require quoting
- If `rating` is an integer, you need to turn it to a decimal before averaging it (otherwise you get an integer average)